# Using alias after a command call

Tags: bash, terminal, alias

I am wondering if I can use an alias after a command call, where my alias is `alias redirect='2>&1 | tee'`. For instance:

```
seq 1 5 2>&1 | tee one2five.txt       # case A
```

case A works.

```
seq 1 5 redirect one2five.txt         # case B
```

case B does not work.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: IIRC, `alias` only substitutes the beginning of a command.

Comment: If you're using bash, you can use the unportable `|&` to pipe both the stdout and stderr, which is shorter to type than `redirect`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a variable defined as :

```
REDIRECT='2>&1 | tee'
```

Then, you need an additional evaluation step to translate the variable on the command line before execution of the command line :

```
eval seq 1 5 ${REDIRECT} one2five.txt
```